# calling generic methods without cast

Tags: java, generics, methods

For generic method like:

```
public static <T> Path<T> getPath(String value) {


}


Path<Number> path = getPath("abc");
Path<String> path = getPath("efg");
```

Compiling error: `Path<Object>` can not be cast to `Path<Number>`.

What is the syntax matching the parameter  with any type? I am using Java 7.

For java 8, without error.

Comment: Does it work if you call `ClassName.<Number>getPath("abc")`?

Comment: works. Thanks. If you make it an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: This method signature is fundamentally unsafe, unless the method always returns an empty "path" or `null`.